# Stop getting multiple emails from trigger

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

SQL Server 2012
I am getting multiple emails when this trigger fires when a record is inserted.  Should only get one email
here is the code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[WOInsertMail] ON [dbo].[WORKORDR]

FOR Update
 AS

 DECLARE @Emails NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @WRKOxml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @WRKOrdBody NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sub NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @WRKOxml = CAST(( 
SELECT convert(varchar(10),ID) AS 'td','',
convert(varchar(20),isnull(Workordno,'')) AS 'td','',
 convert(varchar(20),isnull(WODate,'')) AS 'td','',
 convert(varchar(20),isnull(WOTitle,'')) AS 'td','',
 convert(varchar(20),isnull(engineer,'')) AS 'td','',
convert(varchar(20),isnull(drafter,'')) AS 'td','',
convert(varchar(20),isnull(insertuser,'')) AS 'td','',
convert(varchar(20),isnull(insertdate,'')) AS 'td'

FROM inserted
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SET @WRKOrdBody ='<H3>Work Order Insert</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th>ID</th><th>Workordno</th>
<th>WODate</th><th>WOTitle</th>
<th>Engineer</th><th>Drafter</th>
<th>InsertUser</th><th>InsertDate</th>
</tr>'    
SET @WRKOrdBody = @WRKOrdBody + isnull(@WRKOxml,'') +'</table>'

set @Emails = '<html><body>' + isnull(@WRKOrdBody,'') + '</body></html>'

select  @sub = 'WorkOrder #' + convert(varchar(10),ID) + ' has been inserted         in WO Table on ' + convert(varchar(10),WODATE) 
FROM inserted

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail

 @recipients = 'My@email.com',
@subject = @sub,
@body = @Emails,
@body_format ='HTML'
```

Comment: This looks like an UPDATE trigger.  Do you have another firing on INSERT?

Comment: No.  Would prefer to have it fire on insert but the emails were coming to me blank

Comment: So the code above says "FOR Update".  Are you saying that your actual trigger says "FOR Insert", and that when you insert a record you're getting multiple blank emails?

Answer (score 0):

I'm affraid that the trigger is called for each inserted row separatelly (probably from some .net app) - otherwise line

```
select  @sub = 'WorkOrder #' + convert(varchar(10),ID) + ' has been inserted         in WO Table on ' + convert(varchar(10),WODATE) 
FROM inserted
```

would fail because of trying to insert values from 2+ rows into scalar variable.

Please try to insert 2 or more rows in one insert query from SSMS.